# Java PriorityQueue: Is it better to poll() and then add() or peek() and then remove()

Tags: java, performance, collections, queue

I have just finished my networked job queue and I have a little question relating to the performance of a PriortiyQueue in Java.

Take this code:

```
 private void performJob() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        NetworkJob job = actions.poll();
        if (job.perform()) {
            return;
        }
        actions.add(job); //Job was a failure, add it back to the queue
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

in the case of the job failing, the job still needs to be in the queue. So, my question: Is it better to `poll()` and then `add()` or `peek()` and then `remove()`

I am personally leaning towards the code below, but considering that a job shouldn't really be failing (In most cases, assume it was a pass) is it better to just `poll()`?

```
 private void performJob() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        NetworkJob job = actions.peek();
        if (!job.perform()) {
            return;
        }
        actions.remove(); //Job was a success,  we can remove it from the queue.
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Totally nitpicking and probably not worth worrying about due to the rarely-used nature of the queue, but it interests me and I'd like to see your reasoning.

Full code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public final class NetworkQueue implements Runnable {

    private final Context context;
    private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private final PriorityQueue<NetworkJob> actions = new PriorityQueue<>(5, new NetworkJobComparator());
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition jobReady = lock.newCondition();
    private final Condition networkUp = lock.newCondition();

    private ConnectionType connection = ConnectionType.NONE;

    public NetworkQueue(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        context.registerReceiver(new NetworkListener(),
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (running.get()) {
                waitJobAvailable();
                waitNetworkUp();
                performJob();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setNetwork(ConnectionType net) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            connection = net;
            if (connection != ConnectionType.NONE) {
                networkUp.signal();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void waitNetworkUp() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (connection != ConnectionType.NONE) {
                networkUp.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }


    private void waitJobAvailable() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (actions.isEmpty()) {
                jobReady.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void performJob() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            NetworkJob job = actions.peek();
            if (!job.perform()) {
                return;
            }
            actions.remove();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean addJob(NetworkJob job) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (this.actions.contains(job)) {
                return false;
            }
            this.actions.add(job);
            this.jobReady.signal();
            return true;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void end() {
        this.running.set(false);
    }

    private class NetworkListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo == null) {
                setNetwork(ConnectionType.NONE);
                return;
            }
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                setNetwork(ConnectionType.WIFI);
                return;
            }
            setNetwork(ConnectionType.ANY);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In terms of performance, this will likely (or maybe even *mainly*) depend on the exact implementation of the queue that you are using. Apart from that, you should note that the snippets have different semantics unless they are only used single-threaded.

Comment: @Marco13 I've expanded the snippet a little to show that the queue as a whole is multi-threaded but the code block is locked. What do you mean by the semantics are different?

Comment: If the snippets were not locked (as in the edited version), then two threads that executed the snippets concurrently would either `poll` **different** elements (in the first version), or `peek` at the **same** element (in the second version). This is clear now, but still: Is this a *blocking* queue? Particularly, a `PriorityBlockingQueue`?

Comment: @Marco13 Apologies. No it's a PriorityQueue that is manually locked. I've added the code for clarity, the reason I'm not using a PriorityBlockingQueue is because there is a condition other than the queue not being empty that needs to be signalled after an element has been added.

Comment: `remove` is actually `poll` with extra null-check. `poll/add` is certainly slower than `peek`. You code does different things: in first snippet you `remove/add`, in second you just remove.

Comment: @TagirValeev Ah, that's because I actually wrote the second block in the editor. Fixed. Bear in mind, they're supposed to ultimately do the same thing: Keep the job in the queue if it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard heap-based `PriorityQueue` implementation in OpenJDK and OracleJDK the `peek()` call is extremely fast:

```
public E peek() {
    return (size == 0) ? null : (E) queue[0];
}
```

That's because heap root is always the least element. In contrast removing and adding operations can be quite expensive as they may need to restructure the heap. Thus `peek/remove` solution is likely to be faster.

In my library I have an algorithm to select `n` least elements from the unsorted input. I implemented it using the `PriorityQueue` which preserves at most `n` least elements found so far. First implementation was like `add/poll`. When I [updated](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/181e2bba0d6c660db6e9704a6c22126b91094437?diff=split#diff-bf1456a00583e665c2291887aea00917L524) to use `peek`, the performance was drastically improved (up to 10x on some tests).

Comment: This is what I'm talking about! Awesome, Thank you Tagir.